# Missing Keyword Error - Join Subquery with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Anyone have any experience of this error? I don't use Oracle much, am I missing something very obvious in this query?

I'm thinking its something to do with the way I've used the alias'?

```
SELECT T1.ACC_CDE,
       T3.CUST_DESC,
       T1.PROD_DESC,
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CUST_NO, 
        MIN(CUST_CDE) AS CUSTOMER_CODE 
        FROM SCHEMA.TABLE2
        GROUP BY CUST_NO) SCHEMA.TABLE2 T2 
ON T1.CUST_NO = T2.CUST_NO
LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE3 T3
ON T2.CUST_CDE = T3.CUST_CDE
GROUP BY T1.ACC_CDE,
  T1.PROD_DESC,
  T3.CUST_DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This portion does not make sense:

```
(SELECT CUST_NO, 
        MIN(CUST_CDE) AS CUSTOMER_CODE 
        FROM SCHEMA.TABLE2
        GROUP BY CUST_NO
) SCHEMA.TABLE2 T2
```

It looks like you are giving two aliases to the subquery.  But the first one isn't valid.

Your code could have other problems, but try removing the `SCHEMA.TABLE2` after the `)`.  I presume you want:

```
(SELECT CUST_NO, 
        MIN(CUST_CDE) AS CUSTOMER_CODE 
        FROM SCHEMA.TABLE2
        GROUP BY CUST_NO
) T2
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this changes the error to " "T2"."CUST_CDE": invalid identifier", as if the query cant identify the column in Table2? 

At what point is correct to 'assign' T2 to SCHEMA.TABLE2?